# Magento get the first day of the current week

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

is there any way to get the first day of the current week according to the **current customer locales settings**?

The current date is:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d", Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time()));
```

The current first day of the week by server's settings is:

```
$firstDayOfWeek = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('this week', Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time())));
```

I'm using magento 1.7.* CE version.

Comment: you mean find the sunday or monday of the current week?

Comment: yes, but I need to find it according to the current user's settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know much about magento but if you just need the timestamp then `strtotime` is quite nice for this.

```
$weekBeginning = date('Y-m-d', Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(strtotime('last monday')));
```

Comment: I need the customer's first day of the week, not the server ones. Thank you anyway.